# Invalid regular expression alphanumeric and special characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex for space separated strings containing capital letters, numbers or the special characters ' / - ? : ( ) . , '' (simple quote and double quote included).

I tried the following regex :

```
^[A-Z0-9'\/?:().,\"\- ]*$
```

I'm told that the regex is invalid, and I don't understand why

Comment: [It is valid](https://regex101.com/r/oZUJId/1). Where is it used? In a HTML `pattern` attribute? In Bash? Note `-` must be used at the start/end of the character class - it is the  way of using it in a bracket expression.

Comment: Which engine it is? maybe you need to double escape.

Comment: Right, if you use it in a `RegExp` constructor in JS, you need to double ``\``s.

Comment: It is used in an Angular 7 Validator  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Then it is a backslash issue.